# jQuery: checkbox

Tags: jquery

what's wrong with my code, I don't get any values:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("input[type=checkbox][checked]").each(function(event){
            var get = $("input[@name=\'checkbox_pref\']:checked").val();
            $("#result").html("&id=" + get);
        });
    });
</script>
</head>                                                                 
<body>                                                                
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_pref" value = "1"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_pref" value = "2"/>   
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_pref" value = "3"/>   
<div id="result">result ...</div>
```

Comment: the way I see it, you're doing that function for the checkboxes that are checked on loading. are any of them automatically checked or something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends what you're trying to do, but it should be more along the lines of:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function(event){
        $("#result").html("&id=" + this.value);
    });
});
```

Comment: I agree, although I would do `$('input:checkbox')`

Comment: Thanks, but how get all selected values, no't just last?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to escape the single quotes or the @ symbol.  Use this line:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("input[type=checkbox][checked]").each(function(event){
        var get = $("input[name='checkbox_pref']:checked").val();
        $("#result").html("&id=" + get);
    });
});
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with escaping the single quotes. EDIT: I see you updated your answer to remove the `@` symbol.

Comment: .. I just checked your solution on jsFiddle.net, and it doesn't seem to be working. http://jsfiddle.net/cxhVV/

Answer (score 0):

Having just been checking a very similar type of functionality myself, here is my test. Just as a footnote FYI ;)

http://jsfiddle.net/7Tdgw/